# how to schedule multiple config files in a jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins, I have a jenkins job which has two config files. I want to schedule this job periodically for example first config file to run at 8 pm and second at 10 pm. how to do it ? Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean with config file?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution.
Just create two jobs by cloning the first one and simply change the chron 
configuration for each job as needed.